# Meaning of interrogation

Tags: flowtype

I'm a little bit confuse about the meaning difference of using "?"

I offen saw this:

```
var foo?: number = "bar"
```

But also saw this:

```
function foo(bar: {baz: ?string}) { ... }
```

And also saw both together.

I've read about *invariants* and *maybe types*, but if I understood it right, both signals have the same meaning, which is: **"this type is of kind 'X', but it maybe is null or undefined"**.

Is it right or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Here are answers to most of your questions:

```
// Don't know what this is, or why you would use it
// Error: undefined is incompatible with string
var foo1?: string = undefined;

// ?string means string, null, or undefined
var foo2: ?string = undefined;

type FooOptional = { foo?: string };

type FooMaybe = { foo: ?string };

// If it's optional it can be completely omitted
var foo3: FooOptional = {};
// It can also be explicitly set to undefined
var foo4: FooOptional = { foo: undefined };
// But not null!
var foo5: FooOptional = { foo: null };
// If it's a maybe type, it must be specified
// Error: property `foo` not found
var foo6: FooMaybe = {};
// But you can set it explicitly to null or undefined
var foo7: FooMaybe = { foo: null };
var foo8: FooMaybe = { foo: undefined };
```

([tryflow link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgCJwHYDkALmANZ6JgIAWAhiUdQJYDOYrANGHAE5XUBPMALgBXKmJgATMKJYBTdkQxYAojx68AXLLxT5UJnnkzW7PAGM4AWwAO9JgCMYihE0ZgWRHkYDmqADdaPig4OABGAH4dLx88XzAAXl19Q2MpAG50TDBI2L8wa3laPDZ8+K48URgYLl4UgyMTQOCwULgAJh087wLk0T1G9KzUIgFbRQAxMIB5WyImfFoYJLAAbzaw6M9e+LAAXxGxibBpuABZWgFHRWSN9u7yhMPsrABJKCUCNjh5xbxlkowBYSmAbsCbLYXER5DAhDZ3DCpC0QmEAMw6M5zBZLFZ3F45N4kEF4MDLFhwMGKeQADyhTAs7jhnnkDEpA1STWRQVRcAALJjZn9cat7mEdByhiYDlkcgAhUQkChK6owACEKM2cAArIK4Nj-oC7lqdFUajKVGAPl82LRCldwcd5Fx3IU5CRwSwJozDM0cupNDwdLZNBMeGMwAADdqRsDKzYczXtABsesu11u6wJWAVJBE4hJLJIrtp9MZRGZREpZpW9UlaWaPK1AHY0w7M2K4KbVRam+0ABxtjOik0NBsyQ5AA))

Using both together (e.g. `{foo?: ?string}` as a type) usually (but not in all cases) indicates that the author doesn't quite know what type they want to use and have just added question marks until it typechecks. Typically I have found that if I think it through, it makes sense to use *either* an optional property or a maybe type, but  not both.